# Some questions on Commutative Algebra ; $S[b^{-1}] \cong K[x]/QK[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I have a question.

Let $R$ be an integral domain contained in $S$, also domain. And $S$ is generated by one element of $R$ ; i.e., $S = R[t]$.

Note that $S$ can be expressed as $R[x]/Q$ for some prime $Q$ (by considering the homomorphism $ f: R[x] \to R[t], x \mapsto t$). Assume further that $Q \neq 0$.

And assume that there exists an element $0 \neq b \in S$ such that $S[b^{-1}]$ is a field.
Let $K$ be the quotient field of $R$.

Question.  Then $S[b^{-1}]$ is of the form $K[x]/QK[x]$?

My first attempt is (commented by David Eisenbud) ,

1. Since $R$ is contained in $S[b^{-1}]$ and $S[b^{-1}]$ is a field, $K \subseteq S[b^{-1}]$.
2. Maybe, $S[b^{-1}]$ can be generated by some one element $l$ over $K$.
3. Thus $S[b^{-1}]$ is of the form $K[x]/QK[x]$ or $S[b^{-1}] \cong K[x]/QK[x]$.

But I stuck at the step 2 and 3. Can we provide such an element $l$ explicitly? If so, how? And how can we deduce 3 from 2? Will this argument works well? Or maybe is there any other method?

This question originates from [Nullstellensatz - General form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326148/nullstellensatz-general-form) which I posed but not answered yet.